# Apigee HMAC digest and base64 encoding

Tags: javascript, base64, hmac, apigee, api-gateway

I am trying to move some parts of the signature validation form the service code to the Apigee API gateway.
I have this code in Ruby currently

```
signature = Base64.urlsafe_encode64(OpenSSL::HMAC.digest('sha1', secret, base_string))
```

I am using the Apigee JavaScript policy. 
How do I compute this signature in Apigee? Assuming that I have secret and base_string available as flow variables.

I am stuck figuring out the Javascript code in Apigee which will achieve this.

Current Apigee Javascript code :

```
var _sha1 = crypto.getSHA1();
_sha1.update(secret);
_sha1.update(base_string);
var signature = _sha1.digest64();
```

Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Apigee edge has a hmac policy but surprisingly didn't find any documentation on it. After spending some time, i couldn't get it to work.

Apigee also allows javascript and python extensions. In JS extension there is no way to generate HMAC signature according to the apigee docs. So i ended up using the python extension. Below is the code snippet which worked for me.

```
import hmac
import hashlib
import base64

# secretkey = flow.getVariable('secret')   
secretkey = '432jfe92390ndj23i'
rawStr = 'data we want to hash'

computedHash = hmac.new(secretkey, rawStr, hashlib.sha256)

# digest is the byte str generated    
digest = computedHash.digest()

computedHash = base64.b64encode(digest)

flow.setVariable('signature', computedHash)
```

Hope this helps.